# How to connect Ubuntu virtualbox using "BridgeAdapter"

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, virtual-machine, ifconfig

what i have

```
1. Oracle VM virtualbox installed in Windows7.
2. Ubuntu 12.04 installed in VM.
```

What i am trying

```
1. To connect this VM to host PC using Bridge Adapter
```

What i have achieve so far

```
1. I can connect VM & host PC using NAT
```

Reason for trying Bridge Adapter

```
So that my vm gets IP
```

At present ifconfig gives below output

```
Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:9f:8e:d8  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe9f:8ed8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:78286 errors:63 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:34504 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:62933937 (62.9 MB)  TX bytes:2143610 (2.1 MB)
          Interrupt:10 Base address:0xd020 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1919 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1919 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:38842723 (38.8 MB)  TX bytes:38842723 (38.8 MB)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Ocacle VM VirualBox Manager, press right click on your Ubuntu 12.04 image and press settings.On network tab choose the adapter you wish , lets say adapter 1.The in the attached to: section choose Bridged adapter and for name choose the physical controller. 
Some wirelless adaptors wont usually work with the vms so try to be cable connected and choose your ethernet adapter.